# QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory does not close after choosing a folder

Tags: qt, qfiledialog

In Qt,

```
QFileDialog *dlg = new QFileDialog(); 
QDir dir = dlg->getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Choose folder"), qgetenv("HOME"));
```

opens a folder choose dialog. Once I select a folder (press choose button) the folder is not closing automatically. So I tried:

```
if(dlg->close() == true) delete(dlg);
```

When I debug the dlg->close() returns true and the code delete(dlg) is hit. Still the Folder chooser dialog box is not closing.

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit OS. Using Qt libraries from the repository.

My ultimate aim is just to show a folder chooser dialog and once the folder is chosen the dialog should close. After that processing should continue. How to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: nothing to do with your question but `qgetenv("HOME")` is not as reliable as `QDesktopServices::storageLocation(QDesktopServices::HomeLocation)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even if `QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory` is static and doesn't need a `QFileDialog` object to work, it should close the dialog window when a directory is finally chosen.
By default that function tries to open a native file dialog window, which seems to cause some problems on some platforms.

You should try forcing a non-native dialog by adding the option `DontUseNativeDialog`:

```
QString dir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(
    this, 
    tr("Choose folder"),
    QDesktopServices::storageLocation(QDesktopServices::HomeLocation),
    QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly | QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);
```

And remove the two other lines (with `new QFileDialog` and `if(dlg->close()) ...`).

Comment: Yes exactly using native dialog was the issue. Now the dialog closes after choosing the folder.

Answer (score 1):

`getExistingDirectory(...)` is a static function.

Answer (score 0):

To add to cmannett85's answer:

You should not make an instance of `QDialog`. If you do, it's up to you to hide it. Modify your code to read

```
const QString home = QDesktopServices::storageLocation(QDesktopServices::HomeLocation);
const QDir dir = QFileDialog:getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Choose folder"), home);
```

This code should be relatively portable. `qgetenv("HOME")` is Unix-specific. You should not introduce gratuituous platform-specific code in Qt-based projects -- it sort of defeats the purpose of using Qt in the first place.