# How to close QFileDialog programmatically?

Tags: qt

I need to process and close QFileDialog in tests of the application.
The dialog invoked by:

```
QFileDialog::getOpenFileName( ... );
```

In the test I 'catch' this dialog by:

```
QApplication::topLevelWidgets();
```

Then I choose need file by QFileDialog API.

And now I should close the dialog to get valid answer (filename) from QFileDialog::getOpenFileName();
But QDilaog's slots has no effect (accept(), reject(), close()... ). The dialog stays opened.

The solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284948/qfiledialoggetexistingdirectory-does-not-close-after-choosing-a-folder) works, but it is no option in my case. I must to use standard dialogs.

Is there a way to close it properly?

Comment: `Then I choose need file by QFileDialog API.`. Do you really see your changes in the GUI of the dialog?

Comment: What Qt version do you use? I'm asking, because I'm looking at 4.8 sources and it doesn't create QFileDialog at all (it creates a fake `QDialog` instead). So how do you use the API?

Comment: Yes - the directory and file are chosen properly!

Comment: just call QFileDialog::getOpenFileName( nullptr, message, QString(), mask );

Comment: But you said that you found the dialog by `topLevelWidgets` and than choose a file by API. It means that you have used a pointer not a static API. Otherwise you don't need to find the dialog.

Comment: I don't create object directly. It was created by Qt inside the static function. I just found it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60523/discussion-between-ezee-and-yuriy-velichko).

Answer (score 3):

QFileDialog::getOpenFileName is a static method, so you're limited by what you can do with it.

If you want more control, I suggest creating an instance of QFileDialog and using that instead. By calling the instance's [close()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#close) function, you can programmatically close the dialog.

In response to the comment that this doesn't work, here's example code:-

```
// Must create the FileDialog on the heap, so we can call close and the dialog is deleted
// Set the Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose flag if the instance is still required
QFileDialog* fileDlg = new QFileDialog(this, QString("Select Config file"), QDir::homePath(),    QString("Config (*.xml)"));

// One shot timer to close the dialog programmatically
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
timer->setSingleShot(true);
connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [=]() 
{
    fileDlg->close();
    timer->deleteLater();
} );

timer->start(3000);
fileDlg->exec();
```

Comment: As I said, I "catch" the dialog among app's widgets. (No dlg->getOpenFileName(); dlg->close();)

Comment: close() - has no effect for standard dialog. (It works only for Qt's dialog).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "standard dialog". The code I've added to the answer closes the opened dialog 3 seconds after it has been opened.

Comment: @Merlin069, I think the "standard dialog" stands for the Windows native file open/save dialog that Qt uses.

Comment: From doc for QFileDialog::getOpenFileName() : On Windows, and Mac OS X, this static function will use the native file dialog and not a QFileDialog. Try to use getOpenFileName(), for such dialog close() does not work.

Comment: using Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose - leads to crash inside QFileDialog::getOpenFileName();

Comment: @YuriyVelichko. You have not understood what @Merlin069 meant when he says that `getOpenFileName()` is a static method. If you have `dlg` as an instance of `QFileDialog*`, calling `dlg->getOpenFileName()` does nothing to the `dlg` instance. The dialog that displays is a new instance of `QFileDialog` that is created inside the static function. Rather use the code that @Merlin069 posted in the answer above. Calling `fileDlg->close()` will close the dialog. I suggest you do some research on what static functions are.

Comment: @RobbieE You have not understood what @YuriyVelichko meant when he says that he need to call static method getOpenFileName() which creates `Native` OS dialog instead of Qt dialog `QFileDialog`.

Comment: Please, read the question carefully - I use STATIC function to create the dialog, not dlg->getOpenFileName(). When the dialog (object) is created I found it among application windows using QApplication::topLevelWidgets(); . So I have a pointer to the object that was created INSIDE the getOpenFileName(). Am I right?

Comment: I do not use, and will not use: QFileDialog* fileDlg = new QFileDialog(...)

Comment: Why can't you dynamically allocate the QFileDialog, is it because you don't get the "standard dialog"?

Comment: The only way I know of to get native dialogs is if you call `QFileDialog::exec()` but, on Windows, this results in a modal window so the Qt signals/slots system won't work.

Comment: @RobbieE, For the QFileDialog option QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog, the docs state "By default, the native file dialog is used...", so I'm really confused as to what the problem is. As you can see from the example code in my answer, I also use the exec() function. Of-course, a call to invoke on the close method, from a separate thread, would be possible after the call to exec, if that is desired. Just because it's a model dialog, doesn't mean that the signal slot system does not work.

Comment: I've checked in the background code. Calling `QFileDialog::exec()` results in a call to `IFileDialog::Show()` for native Windows dialog which runs its own event loop, independant of Qt and is a blocking function. In Qt 5, it is possible to call `close()`, which will then call `IFileDialog::Close()` but, as you said, you will only be able to do this from a different thread. Being able to programatically close the native dialog is the entire point of @YuriyVelichko's question, if I understood correctly.

Comment: @RobbieE, so you agree, it is possible to do so programmatically, via a 2nd thread, or am I missing your point?

Answer (score 2):

In order for to display a native dialog, you have to run `exec()` or call one of the static functions.

Unfortunately, in Windows, this calls a blocking function in the Windows API making the displayed dialog modal, running it's own event loop. Without returning to the Qt event loop, you cannot execute the `close()` function using the signals/slots interface.

I tried to bypass this by calling the `close()` function directly from another thread, but this results in Qt trying to send an event to the underlying dialog. Since sending (as opposed to posting) events across thread boundaries is not allowed in Qt, a fatal error is generated.

So, it seems for Windows at least, this is not possible.

I have not tested on platforms other than Windows. The code I used was:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);


    QFileDialog* fileDlg = new QFileDialog(0, QString("Select Config file"), QDir::homePath(),    QString("Config (*.xml)"));

    // spawn a new thread
    QtConcurrent::run([=](){
        QTimer timer;
        timer.setSingleShot(true);

        QEventLoop *loop = new QEventLoop;

        QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [=](){
            fileDlg->close();
            fileDlg->deleteLater();
            loop->quit();
        });

        timer.start(3000);
        loop->exec();

        delete loop;
    });

    fileDlg->exec();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows you can use WinAPI to close the dialog:

```
#define WAIT(A) while (!(A)) {}
HWND dialogHandle, button;
WAIT(dialogHandle = FindWindow(NULL, L"Open")); //write here title of the dialog
WAIT(button = FindWindowEx(dialogHandle, NULL, L"Button", L"&Open")); //write here title of the button to click
SendMessage(button, BM_CLICK, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need multiplatform solution.

Comment: @yuriy-velichko I really doubt that you will succeed in finding a crossplatform solution. Windows-implementaion use winapi call `GetOpenFileName` which doesn't get back until the dialog is closed. So I should be a platform specific way to close such dialog. And it looks like it's not implemented in Qt.